# MRT.exe in weird folders

Tags: windows-8

I was browsing through file using File Explorer on Windows 8 and found some weird directories on the `C:\`. These directories were:

1. `C:\8c1ef7a4b9f7cc7cfee9c4fbfc\`
2. `C:\8c093936d12936232b1c17cb61\`
3. `C:\abbe59686406b1592e29c899\`

Each of these folders contained `MRT.exe`, which from what I have looked up is Microsoft's Malicious Removal Tool. However, when I looked at the exe's properties, I see no copyright nor Microsoft as the company (just blank).

Is this something to be concerned about? I ran a virus scan and nothing showed up, so I assume it isn't a virus.

**NOTE:** I have seen other sites which say it is OK, as long as it has a Microsoft signature (e.g. copyright Microsoft), but mine doesn't...

Also, each exe has a different size: 88,000 KB; 80,000 KB; 84,000 KB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

those files are created every time windows update downloads and runs Microsoft malicious software removal tool.

Idn about why the actual exe files don't show Microsoft properties, apparently they should, maybe The folders them selves have the info? Anyway treat the files as if they were malware. DONT RUN THEM

I recommended you run a quick scan using malware bytes which is a good, accurate free tool. Unlike other overkill virus scanners.

Anyway unsurprisingly the Microsoft says that the program should of deleted the folders and files-

so delete them **after** the virus scan. Empty the recycle bin.

Source:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/multiple-copies-of-mrtexe-in-multiple-folders-on-c/4bce5afd-8881-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?msgId=2853bf94-1c82-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=890830#Faq

Comment: scanned with MalwareBytes and no viruses. Just deleted the directories now

Comment: awesome, glad problem solved